# SQL Server Query Unicode String

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table `UserType`:

```
 id (int),
 type nvarchar(50)
```

I have inserted some rows into that table

```
 INSERT INTO [UserType] VALUES (N'កក្កដា');
 INSERT INTO [UserType] VALUES (N'វិច្ឆិកា');
```

And it's successfully inserted.

Then when I tried to query it back

```
select * 
from [UserType] 
where type=N'កក្កដា';
```

It returns all rows.

What's wrong? Please help!

Comment: `are you serious` what does the `*` in your query mean.. you are telling it to `select * from [UserType] where type=N'កក្កដា';` perhaps you should alter your query to only return `UserType` also do a google search on how to return `Unicode String from Sql Server` I would also recommend reading up on what `SELECT *` means here is a start for you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180059.aspx

Comment: Whats your database collation

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: My database collation is "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you database is `Accent Insensitive`.

You need to `explicitly` mention the proper `collation` name in `where` clause to filter the proper data.

Use `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS` collation which is `accent sensitive`. Try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM   [UserType]
WHERE  type = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), N'វិច្ឆិកា') COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS;
```

Comment: It's working fine now , But I don't want to use COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS in the query.Is there any way?

Comment: @ChhornSoro - Try altering your database collation